# Rote memorization

Tags: word-choice

I heard someone saying "rote memorization" and after that I found from another resource it is not correct to say "rote memorization" and instead it is said simply "rote". How is it correct to say: "Reading again and again is rote memorization" or "Reading again and again is rote"? This is just an example. I hope you understand what I need to know. And how would I properly use this word?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase most commonly used is [**rote learning**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rote_learning), or learning **by rote**, although I don't have a problem with "rote memorisation".

It is unusual to say that something "is rote" in the given context. You can either say "Reading again and again is the definition of learning by rote." or "Reading again and again is the definition of rote learning.". Something that can more commonly *be* rote is learning (or some synonym for learning), but even then the idiomatic use would generally be *by* rote.

EDIT: Thanks to ColleenV for pointing this out: There is another definition of *rote*. You can say something "is rote" if you are describing something that should be creative/inspired, but it is instead mechanical, robotic, uninspired and/or formulaic - as if learned/made "by rote".

Comment: Why can't we say something "is rote"? Rote can mean mechanical and uninspired - "The cellist's playing is rote and lacks any understanding of the emotion of the piece."

Comment: Here is an example from 2015 [...turn the most highly valued digital media sites into something that, in the main, **is rote**, dull, repetitive, and of low value, a form that doesn't warrant and cannot sustain focus...](https://books.google.com/books?id=ptstBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT21&dq=%22is%20rote%22%20-learning&pg=PT21#v=onepage&q=%22is%20rote%22&f=false)

Comment: @ColleenV I think he was thinking only at the question's context.

Comment: @ColleenV Timʘtei is correct, I was thinking of that context. That said, I will edit my answer to include that definition.

Comment: While "by rote" is far more common, I still don't think "is rote" is incorrect. For example, [Learning is rote rather than integrated and cognitive.](https://blog.smu.edu/studentadventures/2008/jackie-in-panama/one-person-at-a-time/) or [ADHD becomes apparent when learning is rote](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/how-do-life/201409/authoritative-look-adhd) I don't mean to nit pick, but I don't want someone to come away from your answer thinking that "is rote" is incorrect when it is perfectly fine English.